# Let $G$ be a group of order $p^nq$. Show that it's p-Sylow subgroup is isomorphic to the factor group $\frac{G}{G^{p^m}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Say I have an **abelian** group $G$ of order $p^nq$, where $p$ is a prime number and $gcd(p,q) =1$.  By the first Sylow theorem there is a subgroup of $G$, let's call it $S$, of order $p^n$. Furthermore let $f: G \to G, g \mapsto g^{p^m}$ and let $G^{p^m}$ be the image of $f$. I want to show that for every $m > n, S \cong \frac{G}{G^{p^m}}$.

My guess is that I have to use the isomorphism theorem for groups likes so:
Define $\phi : G \to S, g \mapsto  g^q$ and then discover, that $\ker(\phi)= G^{p^m}$.(Reminder: $G^{p^m}$ is the image of $f$ as defined above.) Am I on the right track here?

Comment: What is $ G^{p^{m}} $

Comment: it is the image of the function $f$ as defined in the second line

Comment: what do i know about q?

Comment: Why is $G^{p^m}$ a subgroup of $G$ ?

Comment: @Max f is a homomorphism

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis but why is it a homomorphism ?

Comment: @Max $f(g_1g_2)=(g_1 g_2)^{p^{m}}=(g_1g_2)(g_1 g_2).....$ $p^{m}$ times

Comment: @Max i dont know if my group is abelian so.. i actually dont know if it is a homomorphism

Comment: @Max Let $g_1$ and $g_2$ in $f(G)$ then $g_1 g_2^{-1}=(g_1)^{p^{m}}(((g_2)^{p^{m}})^{-1})=(g_1 g_2^{-1})^{p^{m}}$ is this wrong?

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis : it is wrong if the group is not assumed to be abelian. Unless there's some other argument that you've not mentioned; which there may very well be

Comment: @Max  but inst $p^{m}$ times  $(g \dot g \dot .....g)^{-1}=(g)^{-1}(g \dot g.......g)^{-1} $ and so on $--> g^{-1} \dot .... $ $p^{m}$ times?

Comment: My apologies. I should have clarified that $G$ is indeed an abelian Group.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Should have clarified that too: $gcd(p,q) =1$

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis : there's no way you're going to make this work without the abelian hypothesis. OP : ok, then it's clear that $f$ and $\phi$ are morphisms. To answer your question, I think it may work; you simply have to show that $\phi$ is surjective

Comment: @Max, right, and that $ker(\phi)=G^{p^m}$. It turns out to be somewhat tricky though. The problem also looks like Sylow Theorems might be applicable. But I'm uncertain how.

Comment: Well since $G$ is abelian if you decompose it as a product if cyclic groups, it should be clearer

Comment: But do we know how to decompose it? Aren't there many possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $G \cong P \times Q $, where $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup and $Q$ is of order $q$. We may choose $m$ such that $x^{p^m}=1$ for all $x\in P$ (for example, $m=n$ works by Lagrange, but that may not be minimal. But not any $m$ will work. In the OP, no $m$ is defined.)

Note that map $f: G \to G, g\mapsto g^{p^m}$ sends both $P$ and $Q$ to themselves. As no element of $Q$ has an element whose order divides $p^m$, the map $f_{\mid Q}:Q\to Q$ has trivial kernel, thus it is injective, thus bijective by the finiteness of $Q$. This together with the fact that $f_{\mid P}$ is trivial by construction implies that $f(G) = f(P)\times f(Q) = 1 \times Q$, so $G/f(G) \cong (P\times Q)/(1\times Q) \cong P$